# SQL sum multiple values by date into new values by date

Tags: mysql, sql, date, sum

Hi I have reports that have been issued with some regularity but they have an initial value of accounts for when the report value is null.
I would like to create a new variable Accts_N which occurs for School, Year, and date and is the sum of that date's Accts value and the Accts value when the date is null. 
So, using the sample table below, School A Year 2017 would have a Accts_N value of 8 for 2016-01-10 and a value of 12 for 2016-02-10.

```
School | Year | Accts | ReportDate
-------|------|-------|-----------
A      | 2017 | 2     | null
A      | 2017 | 6     | 2016-01-10
A      | 2017 | 10    | 2016-02-10
A      | 2018 | 0     | 2016-01-10
A      | 2018 | 4     | 2016-02-10
B      | 2017 | 9     | null
B      | 2018 | 3     | 2016-2-10
```

I've tried a few different instances of SUM CASE WHEN but I don't think that's the right approach. Can someone suggest a direction for me?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a new column, then a correlated subquery comes to mind:

```
select r.*,
       (select sum(r2.accts)
        from reports r2
        where r2.school = r.school and
              r2.year = r.year and
              (r2.reportdate = r.reportdate or r2.reportdate is null)
      ) as accts_n
from reports r;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
  declare @t table(School nvarchar(50), Year datetime, Accts int, ReportDate datetime)

    insert into @t
    values
        ('A','2017',2,null),
        ('A','2017',6,'2016-01-10'),
        ('A','2017',10,'2016-02-10'),
        ('A','2018',0,'2016-01-10'),
        ('A','2018',4,'2016-02-10'),
        ('B','2017',9,null),
        ('B','2018',3,'2016-01-10')

    select t.School, t.Year, t.ReportDate, t.Accts + ISNULL(tNulls.SumAcctsWhenNull,0)
    from @t t
        outer apply (select t2.School, t2.Year, SUM(Accts) AS SumAcctsWhenNull
                    from @t t2
                    where
                        t2.ReportDate IS NULL AND
                        t2.School = t.School AND
                        t2.Year = t.Year
                    group by t2.School, t2.Year) tNulls
    where
        t.ReportDate IS NOT NULL
```